# Filtering to specific nodes in JSON - use grep or map?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm using the themoviedb.org's API to retrieve information about films. It's returning [this JSON data](https://gist.github.com/1270684).

I need to filter this in two different ways, but not necessarily in the same callback. In one instance I only need to return the genres, and in another instance I need to return *only* the "backdrops" where `size.toLowerCase() == 'original'`, and both instances take place in a `success` for an ajax call, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getInfo/en/json/API_KEY/" + filmID,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
        ...
    }
});
```

Would grep or map be the proper method to use here? Regardless, how can I efficiently retrieve this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use grep for filtering out the right things you wanted and placing them in another array, map would be to add further things to the JSON by performing a specific function on each element

```
var results = array();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.getInfo/en/json/API_KEY/" + filmID,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(data){
        data = eval(data);
        results = $.grep(data, function(data) {
            return data[0].posters.image.size == "original";
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `data.posters.size` is returning an empty array, and changing it to `data.posters.image.size` throws the following error: `"TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.posters.image.size')"`

Comment: any better now? lol, it's just a case of getting the indexes right, sometimes nested stuff is hard to read!

Comment: Sorry, no. What's the `eval` for?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `$.map` -- if you only need to return the genres, `$.map` will let you build an array of just those pieces of the object, while `$.grep` will build an array of complete movie objects.