# How to parse JSONP response returned by api.themoviedb.org?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm using themoviedb.org API to fetch the movie info. This is the code I'm using:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/XXX/immortals?callback=foobar", true);
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
      console.log(req.responseText); 
   }
}
```

And I'm getting this response in the console:

```
foobar([{"score":null,"popularity":3,"translated":true,"adult":false,"language":"ru","original_name":"Immortals","name":"Immortals","alternative_name":"\"War of the Gods\"","movie_type":"movie","i".......}])
```

How do I parse this response to get the `name` attribute?

---

**Updates:**

Thank you everybody but the actual answer was given by [hippietrail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527702/hippietrail).

```
eval(req.responseText)
```

More details: [Filtering to specific nodes in JSON - use grep or map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690168/filtering-to-specific-nodes-in-json-use-grep-or-map)

Comment: **1)** You've passed a callback function name (`callback=foobar`), but you haven't provided that callback function. **2)** You're doing a `JSON` call (`GET`) but the API provides `JSONP`, which requires a `script` tag injection instead. The API doesn't support `CORS` anyway so `JSONP` is your only option.

Comment: Possible duplicate: **[How to make a jsonp call to an api using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221458/how-to-make-a-jsonp-call-to-an-api-using-jquery)**

Comment: Also related: **[Filtering to specific nodes in JSON - use grep or map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690168/filtering-to-specific-nodes-in-json-use-grep-or-map)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this function to your page :

( i see its an **array**  - so i'll iterate each item... - if you want the first one only - so please specify.)

```
  function foobar(x)
    {
        $.each(x, function ()
        {
           alert(this.score);
        });

    }
```

http://jsbin.com/ojomej/edit#javascript,html

Comment: shouldn't it be `x[0].name` in his case?

Comment: Adding the function alone won't help. You'd still have to call ist ... so either eval() the returned text or create a script and attach it to the DOM

Comment: @Andy he didnt request the first one. i give him all. he should sepcify it.

Comment: I am not. Your example doesn't include the fact that the returned Text included the call to the function foobar, which doesn't get called without any code actually calling it

Comment: @devnull69 the question was `How to parse JSONP response ` this is the answer. add the function. thats all

Comment: Nope. Just adding a function won't call it

Comment: @devnull69 just adding a function wont call it - correct. when the response comes from the server it comes as Executeable JS script. and he will run it ! the response is `foobar([{...}])`. so when it caomes back he automatically run it !

Comment: Sorry no. It's just the responseText of an Ajax request. And text won't execute anything. Look at the OP's code

Comment: @devnull69 of course it wont! you have to use  $.getJSON or script tag (wrapper). I only answered how to parse the object !

Comment: @devnull69 I think  we are talkinga bout the same thing here

Comment: You're most probably right. But you were the one contradicting me in the first place. But let's settle

Answer (score 3):

The URL you're using is for a JSONP call (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). JSONP is used when cross domain request through XMLHttpRequest are not allowed. But you're using XMLHttpRequest already so I believe you don't need a JSONP call. So, if you remove the querystring from the URL:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/XXX/immortals", true);

req.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
      console.log(req.responseText); 
   }
}

req.send();
```

You should get a JSON string:

```
[{"score":null,"popularity":3,"translated":true,"adult":false,"language":"ru","original_name":"Immortals","name":"Immortals","alternative_name":"\"War of the Gods\"","movie_type":"movie","i".......}]
```

That you can parse using `JSON.parse` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON):

```
var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
```

Now you have a JavaScript object, in your case an array of objects, that you can use:

```
console.log(data[0].name) // "Immortals"
```

However, because the question is tagget "jquery", if you're using that library you can simplify a lot:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/XXX/immortals", function (data) {
    console.log(data[0].name)
});
```

jquery will also take care of the browsers differences (e.g if the browser doesn't support JSON object).

Hope it helps.

Comment: *"JSONP is used when cross domain request through XMLHttpRequest are not allowed"* They're never allowed, that's why JSONP is needed.

Comment: If the code the OP wrote gives the actual response using XMLHttpRequest, it means that website allows cross domain requests through CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Comment: @amnotiam: Your information is out of date, cross-domain requests are allowed when the site supports `CORS` [(Cross-origin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Though the current versions of Opera and Internet Explorer don't implement the standard yet they will both in their next version update.

Comment: @ZER0: I checked and the site doesn't support CORS: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/XXX/immortals?callback=foobar. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: And because of the lack of CORS support at the web API provider this answer won't work either. You'll need to convert it to do `SCRIPT` tag injection... or leave it out and just go with the jQuery solution since the OP originally tagged it with [tag:jquery].

Comment: @hippietrail, ZER0: Fair points, but when testing the code, the request is not permitted, so JSONP is needed. Some browsers will allow the request when it is made from the filesystem or localhost. EDIT: ...I see my comment is a little late. :)

Comment: @hippietrail I assumed that because I don't have a valid key (the XXX part) the site could not reply with the proper CORS header. Reading the original post it seems it reply to the XMLHttpRequest properly. If it's not the case, yes, the OP needs JSONP and therefore he doesn't have to use XHR object, more likely just [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with the "?callback" as parameter.

Comment: @ZER0: Ah yes good point I hadn't considered. I've not used any CORS APIs which require credentials so I'm not familiar with their behaviours.

Comment: @amnotiam as I said, I assumed the code the OP wrote gives the response as he wrote, therefore CORS is supported. I do not have a valid key to test it (the XXX part), so I cannot say if it's support or not the CORS. Of course if the question itself is wrong – so the code doesn't return the JSON string even with a valid key, but just fails – that's a different matter. And yes, he needs to use JSONP instead of XMLHttpRequest object if it's the case.

Comment: A similar question actually contains an API key so I was able to confirm that `JSONP` works using jQuery and `JSON` does not, so the site doesn't support `CORS`. The OP probably got the results he was able to paste in by testing his URL directly in the browser URL bar, using wget, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an API key to test this, but it seems you're not very familiar with either jQuery nor JSON. Anyway something like this might get you started:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/XXX/immortals?callback=?",
   function(data) {
      alert(data[0].name);
   }
);
```